# Absolute positioned content overlapping footer

Tags: html, css

I have the following html...

```
<div class="maincontent">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at metus nisi. Sed blandit, nunc eget ornare porta, lorem est cursus eros, in ultricies enim mi eget leo. Integer a odio at neque lobortis fermentum ac at purus. Vivamus faucibus nec tortor at sagittis. Nam lectus metus, scelerisque vehicula orci ac, lacinia elementum lorem. Nam efficitur mauris quis tortor efficitur, vitae viverra metus semper. Nunc id euismod purus.

<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    Box 1 Content
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    Box 2 Content
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    Box 3 Content
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<footer>
  This is the footer
</footer>

.container{position:relative;}
.box1{position:absolute;top:0;background:red;color:white;}
.box2{position:absolute;top:20px;background:green;color:white}
.box3{position:absolute;top:40px;background:blue;color:white;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/25w7cxv1/

For some reason the footer isn't displaying correctly and is being overlapped by the rest of the content.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving each `.box` a `position:absolute`, you are taking them OUT of the document flow and then positioning them absolutely compared to their positioned parent (or ancestor).

`<footer>` is still in the document flow, and so will appear directly after the text in `.maincontent`.

Here I have removed `position:absolute` so that the boxes remain inline within the document:

```
.container{position:relative;}
.box1{background:red;color:white;}
.box2{background:green;color:white}
.box3{background:blue;color:white;}
```

And here I have given the boxes a property of `display: table` so that they are only as wide as their contents:

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {display: table;}
```

I think this does what you were trying to achieve.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmncpn82/